# WMI and C++ using FireBreath

Tags: c++, activex, wmi, firebreath

I am trying to get user hardware information by creating a browser plugin . It queries WMI using c++ . Does end user need to have c++ runtime in order to run the plugin ?

I created activex which uses c# in the backend but I cant run it on firefox so I had to use FireBreath with c++ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Neil said on the mailing list, not if you statically link (which FireBreath does by default)